# Searching for a specific word in a div

Tags: javascript, if-statement, indexof

I'm not 100% sure if my JavaScript is correct, however it is showing 'Testing' even though I have 'FEW' as a text value - it should pick this up and bar = "Medium", however it didn't.

```
if (document.getElementById('raw').innerHTML.indexOf("CLR") != -1) {
    bar = "Excellent";
} else if (document.getElementById('raw').innerHTML.indexOf("FEW") != -1) {
    bar = "Medium";
} else {
    bar = "Testing";
}  
document.getElementById("bar").innerHTML = bar;
```

The HTML:

```
<p>Live: </p><div class="d-none" id="raw"></div>

<div class="d-none">
    <h5>Test: <span id="bar"></span>.</h5>
</div>
```

Comment: indexOf is case sensitive. Try toUpperString().

Comment: Can you share your HTML?

Comment: Don't use `.innerHTML` when your string doesn't contain any. `innerHTML` has security and performance implications. Use `.textContent` instead.

Comment: <div class="d-none" id="raw"></div> is my HTML corresponding to this part. "raw" is text fetched from an API.

Comment: Where is "CLR" and "FEW" coming from?

Comment: Sorry, I sent the wrong code. This is the part: <div class="d-none">
            <h5>Test: <span id="bar"></span>.</h5></div>

Comment: Please, edit your post and add the whole code. And explain what's wrong ? It works (see my answer)

Comment: I've edited my original post to show the HTML code. "raw" is text taken from an API.

Comment: So what's the problem ? Maybe you call your JS function to early ? Or maybe you forgot to remove `d-none` class on your div ?
What you get from your code ? What come from the API ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks ok.

Keep in mind that `indexOf` is case sensitive. And avoid to get few times the same element, prefer store it into a variable your element or the whole HTML.

Have a look on my snippet

```js
var html = document.getElementById('raw').innerHTML;

if (html.indexOf("CLR") != -1) {
    bar = "Excellent";
} else if (html.indexOf("FEW") != -1) {
    bar = "Medium";
} else {
    bar = "Testing";
}

document.getElementById("bar").innerHTML = bar;
```

```css
.d-none {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<p>Live: </p><div class="d-none" id="raw">blablablablaCLRblabla</div>

<h5>Test: <span id="bar"></span>.</h5>
```